# DBSCAN returns TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cluster-analysis, dbscan, anomaly-detection

Hi I have a dataframe that looks like this. When I try to run a dbscan to search for outliers or anomalies

"model = DBSCAN(eps = 0.4, min_samples = 5).fit(dataframe)"

it return me this error

"TypeError: invalid type promotion"

Is there anyway I can rectify this?

```
    DateTime            Values
0   2020-12-18 15:44:00 554.0
1   2020-12-18 15:57:00 594.0
2   2020-12-18 15:58:00 513.0
3   2020-12-18 16:09:00 576.0
4   2020-12-18 16:10:00 654.0
... ... ...
881 2020-12-27 13:55:00 484.0
882 2020-12-27 14:09:00 491.0
883 2020-12-27 15:17:00 512.0
884 2020-12-27 15:54:00 529.0
885 2020-12-27 17:03:00 436.0
```

Comment: I notice that this error only surfaces when I have a time series column, which is Date Time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of DBSCAN to find outliers in the Titanic data set.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
titanic = titanic.copy()
titanic = titanic.dropna()
titanic['age'].plot.hist(
  bins = 50,
  title = "Histogram of the age variable"
)

 
from scipy.stats import zscore
titanic["age_zscore"] = zscore(titanic["age"])
titanic["is_outlier"] = titanic["age_zscore"].apply(
  lambda x: x <= -2.5 or x >= 2.5
)
titanic[titanic["is_outlier"]]

ageAndFare = titanic[["age", "fare"]]
ageAndFare.plot.scatter(x = "age", y = "fare")

 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
ageAndFare = scaler.fit_transform(ageAndFare)
ageAndFare = pd.DataFrame(ageAndFare, columns = ["age", "fare"])
ageAndFare.plot.scatter(x = "age", y = "fare")

 
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
outlier_detection = DBSCAN(
  eps = 0.5,
  metric="euclidean",
  min_samples = 3,
  n_jobs = -1)
clusters = outlier_detection.fit_predict(ageAndFare)

clusters

from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Accent')
ageAndFare.plot.scatter(
  x = "age",
  y = "fare",
  c = clusters,
  cmap = cmap,
  colorbar = False
)
```

[image]

Those two dots at the top center are two outliers and they are highlighted green.

Comment: Hi appreciate that. But just that the the issue that causes the "TypeError: invalid type promotion" is due to my datetime column where the object type is datetime64ns, which I am not sure why it can trigger the error.

Comment: The data type of datetime64ns sounds fine. Can you drop that field and re-run the process? Maybe there is some kind of anomaly in that field. Maybe something is a NAN or you have some negative value. Maybe you have a weird character in that field. Try to sort the field ascending and descending and see what you see. Then, re-run the process. Sometimes it's trial-and-error with these things.